# Casting a display object to particular Movie Clip - destroys all other instances of that MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a gameboard drawn in flash, with a collection of [Piece] symbols I export with linkage settings and reference via the as3 code. I listen to when the gameboard is added to the stage then recurse the list - checking the following

```
var child:DisplayObjectContainer = dOC.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObjectContainer;
if(child.toString() == "[object Piece]")
{
     //here i want to set some properties on the piece. 
}
```

The problem I have is when I want to obtain a reference to this piece ie

```
var piece:Piece = new Piece();
piece = child as Piece;
```

By casting the child as Piece, all the pieces on the gameboard disappear except 1 - so It seems I am overwriting all the [object Piece] in the game. Each of the pieces in the fla has a unique name so I'm curious as to why getting a ref to the piece and casting it would nuke my board.

Can provide more info if requested

Cheers!

**Edit:**

To give a bit more context - I create 00s of MovieClips using JSFL with names like row_1_col_3 etc. I have a robotlegs setup with a Piece.as - so I use a command (MXP) to swap all MovieClips to a type of Piece. So far the only way to distinguish between pieces is setting the stage instance name in JSFL. When I perform the swap - I get all the Pieces able to be mediated and I know which one was clicked and can send a message to other players. But I would love to initialize each separate piece with their own PieceData class (with row,column, pieceOwner variables) which requires me obtaining a reference from the stage after ADDED_TO_STAGE. The idea being I can draw my board in illustrator and have JSFL wire up the pieces - previously this was all in code but Im trying to have design workflow for the gameboard.

Comment: Are you sure it's that line that is changing everything ? Would have to see the project to be able to see how it's designed etc. Does the same thing happen if you just go : `var piece:Piece = child as Piece;` ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response - I added a bit more info , I had tried your line of code it makes sense that it should work. Could it be the fla has all pieces on the same frame and layer it could be getting confused?

Comment: It's impossible for me to know without looking at how everything is setup. That line shouldn't change all the other instances of Piece, but there might be more to it than that. Are you sure it happens as soon as that line is executed ? Or is other code executed from there before the occurrence ?